# 3 phase voltage problem when connecting to servo

Tags: voltage, power, servo

I have 380V 3 phase with the following line to neutral voltages: L1: 238V, L2: 234V, L3: 224V. The system has a single phase servo driver that takes in L3 and N, however when hooked up L1, L2, and L3, change to the following: 394V, 400V, 0V. I'm not sure why this discrepancy is happening.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmV1QQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. You have a broken neutral.*

Comment: In slightly more detail: you're using three voltmeters with roughly balanced impedances, or there's some conductance and/or capacitance from your local neutral to the neutral reference of your power coming in that keeps things balanced.  So when you put that super-high impedance voltmeter on the wires, you read roughly what you should with a connected neutral.  But when you hook up an actual load, it overwhelms whatever wimpy connection there is, and just holds L3 at zero volts.